# CORS error in Cloud Functions v2 for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have a CORS problem calling my cloud function through a web application.
The same cloud function works perfectly if the call is made via POSTMAN

this is the funcion declaration:
`exports.importScorm = functionsV2.https.onRequest({region: 'europe-west3', cpu: 4, memory: "4GiB", timeoutSeconds: 600 }, importScorm);`

this is the importScorm function:

```
export default async (
  request: functionsV2.https.Request,
  response: functions.Response
) => {

  const { appId, cloudStoragePath, activityId } = request.body;

  console.log(
    JSON.stringify({
      severity: 'info',
      message: '0 - Funzione import SCORM invocata',
      request: request.body,
    })
  );

  // 1. Unzippo il file

  const timeStart = Date.now();

  const destinationFolder = await unzipFileInGCSFromURL(
    cloudStoragePath
  );

  console.log(
    JSON.stringify({
      severity: 'info',
      message: '1 - File unzippato',
      timePassed: Date.now() - timeStart
    })
  );

  // 3. Estraggo i file

  await importActivityFromXMLPath(destinationFolder, appId);

  response.send({
    destinationFolder,
  });

  return;

};
```

and this is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuKMt.png)

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help with this.

I tried with Postman and it works great.

---

SOLVED

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade?hl=it#update_trigger_definitions

`exports.importScorm = functionsV2.https.onRequest({cors:true, region: 'europe-west3', cpu: 4, memory: "4GiB", timeoutSeconds: 600 }, importScorm);`

in v2 you can add easly {cors:true} in options

Comment: Are you using express in your function? Are you setting express to use cors (`app.use(cors())` )?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be better practice to move your "SOLVED" section to an answer and self-accept it - for future viewers to find and upvote.

Comment: Be aware that `cors:true` bypasses CORS security, allowing all origins to call your function. If you are exposing an API to the world that's OK, but if you intend to call it from a specific app domain, then you have lost that defence. To limit it to specific domain you can set it to `cors:"https://myapp.com"` or use an array or regexp

Answer (score 0):

As @NoNam4 explained, if you are using express you can simply add the cors package to express middleware using

```
var cors = require('cors')
//Other stuff you are doing with express
app.use(cors())
```

However if you don't want to add any extra package or use express, you can simply add appropriate header values to the response context. In response to the OPTIONS request, the cloud functions would include CORS headers in its response. Afterwards, your browser will then evaluates the CORS headers in the OPTIONS response to determine if the actual cross-origin request is allowed or not. You can also check in your function code weather it an options request (or  just that req.body is not empty before executing the rest of the code in your function) and only then add in the below headers and send an empty 200 response back with just the headers while only executing your function code if it is not an options request. (Otherwise, you might see some errors in the logs which might be failing because the request body is empty for the options request)

```
 //Call this function as the first thing in your cloud function
 addHeaderToResponse()

//In this example, it is allowing request from all origins. (*). You can 
//specify the origin as well.

export function addHeaderToResponse(response: Response): void {

// Allow requests from any origin (CORS)
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

// Define the allowed request headers
// If you decide to send any other extra headers, you are going to need to 
// add the header name here. Otherwise, it will complain of the same thing 
// again.
response.setHeader(
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content- 
 Type, " +
  "Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-H 
 eaders,authorization, __RequestVerificationToken",
);
```

}

Comment: This was for v1 (1st Gen) whereas the OP asked for v1 (presumably 2nd Gen) where it's done differently. `onRequest({cors:true}, ... )`